# Xamarin Forms Android EntryCell Underline

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tableview, custom-renderer

I need to remove the default underline as seen in this image
[EntryCell Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AOcj.png)

I have already created a custom Renderer for Android which is working fine on the device. I am able to color the `EntryCells` along with other UI tweaks.

However I need to get rid of the line, I am using a placeholder to make it obvious that it is an `EntryCell` so I don't want the line to be visible. What needs to be added to achieve this

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using App.Droid.CustomRenderer;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using EntryCellRenderer = App.Droid.CustomRenderer.EntryCellRenderer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryCell), typeof(EntryCellRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.CustomRenderer
{
 public class EntryCellRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.EntryCellRenderer
{ 

        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context) as EntryCellView;

            if (cell != null)
            {
                var textField = cell.EditText as TextView;

                textField.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 20);
                textField.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex("#FF8800").ToAndroid());
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(Color.FromHex("#FF8800").ToAndroid());


            }

            return cell;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else trying to remove the underline, add this to your Android Custom Renderer:

```
textField.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```